# Is that still a SEO friendly URL if it has duplicates

Tags: support, seo

I have been researching SEO and I am aware that Content is King etc.
but now i come to a more specific thing, SEO friendly URL, which is widely discussed by public. 
I also read Google's Webmaster guide where it talks about duplicate content which generally means that a same page of content should not be pulled up by more than one URL.

So I tested what happens to my website on Stack Overflow, but I actually find out the same "issue" (maybe this is not an issue).

The following URLs has same content, could anyone shed some light here?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315885/cakephp-seo-friendly-urls-with-reversible-ids
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315885/cakephp-seo-friendly-urls-with-reversible-ids/sdfasdf

Comment: I'm voting to close as this question is explicitly about SEO, with SO only being used as an example.

Answer (score 10):

This is why all SO pages have a "canonical" link:

```
  <link rel="canonical" href="http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94822/is-that-still-a-seo-friendly-url-if-it-has-duplicates">
```

this link defines the "original", canonical version of the content on this page.

Read more about it on the [Google Webmasters Blog.](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html)

Comment: Thanks for that~ I am happy with this answer~ I also find another way to tackle this problem on my website. Insteading of doing this, i am able to do 301 redirect all those url to a canonical url in a programmatic way~ I assume that will achieve same thing, am i right?

Comment: @NotFree I'm not sure. Try asking (or searching, I'm sure this has been covered already) over at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com